# Add text to each line of find command

Tags: bash

I have a script and i'm using this to find and list files that end with .txt in the tmp folder

```
find /tmp -type f \( -name '*.txt' \) |cut -c14-
```

The output is something like this:

```
xpto.txt
abc.txt
xyz.txt
```

But i want to add an index at the beggining of each line

```
1 - xpto.txt   
2 - abc.txt
3 - xyz.txt
```

Can anyone help me? i'm still learning bash, started 1 month ago.

Comment: [`man nl`](http://www.ss64.com/bash/nl.html)

Comment: [bashref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
find /tmp -type f \( -name '*.txt' \) |cut -c14- | nl
```

But the `find` command does not always works very friendly with pipes in my experience.

so you could do also this:

```
cd /tmp ; ls *.txt | nl
```

or this (for a different output layout)

```
cd /tmp ; ls *.txt | grep -n ""
```

Comment: But `find` will also list files that are in a subdirectory, while `ls` won't.

Comment: @pfnuesel, that is a very correct remark... to let it work with `find` however,the `cut` command also needs some tinkering to let it work. Also he will probably need `xargs` to process the output of `find` further.  No harm in trying different approaches :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try piping command output to following `awk`

```
awk -v OFS="-" '{print NR, $0}'
```

---

`perl` variant

```
perl -lne 'print $.,"-",$_'
```